# Programmatically access Execution Transcripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api, clasp

I need to access the Execution Transcripts like accessing the Logger logs. For example, I could set `Logger.log` data to a  spreadsheet cell or email using `getLogs()`. How to access Execution Transcripts in a similar way?

Comment: Do you ask about "Execution transcript"? If my understanding is correct, unfortunately it cannot be retrieved yet. But recently, several methods for logging were added. You can see about it at [Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) and [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/). As one of workaround, you might be able to retrieve the information that you need, by combining them. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: A1. You can use [Class console](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console). You can see the logs by ``console.log()`` at stackdriver by opening View -> Stackdriver Logging on script editor. About the payment, You can see [Free logs](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing?hl=en#free_logs).

Comment: A2. In the current stage, the log of "Execution transcript" cannot be retrieved by one method. But I think that the log like "Execution transcript" can be retrieved by putting it to several parts using "Class console". About the log like "Execution transcript", you can also achieve it using [Class Logger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger). A3. Yes. And also "process" can be used. These can retrieve the situation for running methods in the project. Is my understanding for your comment correct?

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I posted it. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, "Execution transcript" cannot be retrieved directly yet. But by Google's recent update, several methods for logging the situation of scripts were added. The detail information of Logging can be seen at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging.

1. [Class Logger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger)

   - These are the conventional methods.
2. [Class console](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console)

   - These are new methods.
   - The size, life time and detail of the retrieved logs are better than Class Logger.
   - About the payment, You can see [Free logs](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing?hl=en#free_logs).
3. [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/)

   - These are new methods.
   - I think that [Resource: processes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes) and [projects.getMetrics](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getMetrics) can be used to retrieve the operating conditions of scripts.

In the current stage, the log of "Execution transcript" cannot be retrieved by one method. But I think that the log like "Execution transcript" can be approached by putting it to several parts using above methods. About this, when I got new information, I would like to report here as an additional information. And I also would like to try to think of such applications.

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you, too. Kotira koso!